# No valida condicional con array en php

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, array

Tengo un formulario que me suma la cantidad total de todos los abonos. Coloco una condicional donde me indica si el array tiene datos me imprima el total de lo contrario  me imprima un mensaje.

No se cual es mi error, pero no me imprime el mensaje. Me sigue imprimiendo el del array con valor pero obvio vació.

Aca dejo el codigo que tengo:

**reportes.php**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Reportes</title>
 <?php include 'inc/head_comun.php'; ?>
 </head>
 <body>
 <?php include 'inc/menu.php'; ?>

<div class="container" >
<br>
<div class="panel panel-success">
  <div class="panel-heading" align="center"><h3>REPORTES</h3></div>
  <div class="panel-body">

    <form class="form-inline" align="center" method="POST" action="reportes.php">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="nombre" >Fecha inicial: </label>
        <input class="form-control " id="nombre" type="date" name="fecha_in" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"/>
      </div>
      &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Fecha final: </label>
        <input class="form-control"  id="email" type="date" name="fecha_fin" value="<?php echo date("Y-m-d");?>"/>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" name="buscar">Buscar</button>
    </form>
    <br>

    <?php

    require_once "modelo/Conectar.php";

    $con=Conectar::conexion();

    if (isset($_POST["buscar"])) {

      $fecha_inicio=$_POST["fecha_in"];
      $fecha_final=$_POST["fecha_fin"];

      $sql=$con->prepare("SELECT TRUNCATE(SUM(cantidad),3) as total from abono Where fecha BETWEEN :fecha_in AND :fecha_fin");
      $sql->execute(array(':fecha_in'=>$fecha_inicio, ':fecha_fin'=>$fecha_final));
      $filas=$sql->fetchAll();

if (count($filas)>0){

echo "hay".var_dump($filas);
}else{
echo "esta vacia ".var_dump($filas);
}


    /*  if (count($filas)>0) {

       foreach ($filas as $registros){

        ?>

        <div class="form-group form-inline" align="center"  style="border-image: initial; border: 1px solid green;">
          <h3>Total cobro entre fechas:
            <span class="label label-warning"> <?php echo $registros["total"];?> $
            </span></h3>
          </div>

          <?php
        }

      }else{
        este es el mensaje que no me imprime cuando no hay abonos con las fechas ingresadas
        echo "No hay abonos en las fechas indicadas";
      }*/

    }

    ?>

    <?php include 'inc/piePagina.php' ?>
    <?php include 'inc/footer_comun.php'; ?>

  </body>
  </html>
```

El resultado  del condicional cuando es mayor que cero del `var_dump` es: `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["total"]=> string(6) "90.000" [0]=> string(6) "90.000" } } hay`

En caso contrario el resultado que me imprime es: `array(1) { [0]=> array(2) { ["total"]=> NULL [0]=> NULL } } hay`

Comment: Qué te devuelve el var_dump($filas)? Si es un array deberías preguntar if (count($filas)>0)) {....}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El método `fetchAll` del `PDO` devuelve un `array`. Por lo tanto `$filas=$sql->fetchAll();` crea la variable `$filas` de tipo `array`.

Para saber la cantidad de elementos de un array debes usar la funcion `count`.

La comparación del `if` esta errada. Esa comparación siempre da true.
Debes reemplazar tu linea del `if` por esta...

```
if (count($filas)>0) {
```

---

### Actualización

Al principio parecía que solo era un problema de que no considerabas que el retorno era un array sin embargo hay otro inconveniente con el tipo de consulta que realizas a la BD.

La función agregada `SUM` siempre retorna por lo menos un registro. En este caso en particular donde no hay `GROUP BY` retornará solo uno siempre.

- Si uno o más registros cumplen la condición retorna la suma de los mismos
- Si ningún registro cumple la condición retorna el valor `NULL`

Consultar si la cantidad de elementos es mayor a 0 siempre dará verdadero y está errado en la lógica. Por lo tanto la consulta que debes realizar es si el valor de retorno en el array es nulo o no.
Algo así como...

```
if (is_null($filas[0][0])) { // Aquí va la parte donde ningún registro cumplió la condición
    echo "No hay abonos en las fechas indicadas";
}
else { // Aqui va la parte donde obtienes una suma
     foreach ($filas as $registros){ // En realidad aquí habrá un solo registro con ese query. La suma de los abonos.
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: @Si, estaba errado. pero no entiendo por que sigue sin mostrar el echo en el caso que este vacía? No he podido solucionar eso.

Comment: Deberías capturar el contenido de `$fecha_inicio`, `$fecha_final` y `$filas` usando `error_log` o escribiendo en el browser para ver realmente que trae y analizar si no es un problema de la consulta aunque todo parace OK con la parte del PDO.

Comment: realice esto: iif (count($filas)>0){

  echo "hay".var_dump($filas);
}else{
 echo "esta vacia ".var_dump($filas);
}mcuanto es mayo me imprime el mensaje y el valor que hay. pero cuando no, me sigue imprimiendo el mensaje pero el de "hay" y me muestra el array en null. ¿Que podria ser?

Comment: No me es claro tu prueba. Podrías editar tu pregunta e incluir los valores que son pasados a la pagina, el valor del array filas, el valor del count de ese array. Para todos los casos posibles: con registros y sin registros.

Comment: Ya coloque el código de la prueba que realice.

Comment: La consulta SUM que realizas siempre retorna una fila. Cuando no hay registros SUM retorna null y no la suma. Hay que preguntar si la fila que retorno es null o es un valor. Como no tengo PDO no puedo replicar tu problema es por eso que te pido que edites tu pregunta y que coloques **el resultado** de `var_dump($filas)` en ambos casos; NO el codigo que ejecutas.

Comment: Listo ya lo agregue en la pregunta.

Comment: Respuesta actualizada. Avisame que tal te va.

Comment: Excelente, solucionado.